# Twilio: Invalid parameter with Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio, serverless

I'm trying to use the `verify` API with twilio. Here is what i have

```
dotenv.config();
import twilio from "twilio";
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);


try {
    let { to } = req.body;

    to = String(to).startsWith("+") ? to : "+" + to;
    to = String(to).trim().replace(/\s/, ""); // no spaces

    console.log(accountSid, to);
    const response = await client.verify
      .services(accountSid as string)
      .verifications.create({
        to,
        channel: "call", // sms, call, or email
      });
    return res.status(200).json(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  error: Invalid parameter,
  status: 400,
  code: 60200,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200',
  details: undefined
}
```

Here is what my `to` looks like `"+2661890..."`. What maybe possibly the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong `SERVICE_SID` i used `ACCOUNT_SID` instead of `SERVICE_SID`. I changed my code to:

```
...
const { sid } = await client.verify.services.create({
      friendlyName: "Verification Service",
    });
const response = await client.verify.services(sid).verifications.create({
      to,
      channel: "call", // sms, call, or email
});
```